# My ArrayList is returning null even though I am getting output on the console

Tags: java, email, arraylist

I am trying to extract OTP from an email. I am able to see the email that I want to extract on the console, but whenever I use regex to extract the OTP it does not.

When I print the ArrayList it prints [null], but when I print size it shows '1'.

And on the console also the email body that I want to extract OTP from is also printed.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the code for the emailOTP Utility:

```
public class emailOTPUtility {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, Exception{
        
        EmailUtils emailUtils = new EmailUtils();
        
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("/Users/xxxx/Automation/src/main/java/Resources/config-email-otp.properties"));
        Store connection = emailUtils.connectToGmail(prop);
        //emailUtils.getUnreadMessages(connection, "Inbox");
        
        List<String> emailtext = emailUtils.getUnreadMessageByFromEmail(connection, "Inbox", "dummmy@gmail.com", "Email ID verification");
        
        System.out.println("this is email:" + emailtext.isEmpty());
        if(emailtext.size()<1)
            throw new Exception("No Email Recieved");
        else
        {
            String emailText1 = emailtext.toString();
            
            System.out.println("this is email:" + emailtext);
            
            System.out.println("the text is:" + emailText1);
            
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"code is:  <b>(\\d{4}+)\"gm");

            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(emailText1);
            
            if (m.find()) {
                System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0));
                System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
                System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2));
            } else {
                System.out.println("NO MATCH");
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

And this is the console output where the ArrayList emailtext returns null. The OTP is in bold.
Below you can see that the ArrayList prints [null] and when size is printed it prints 1(not there in console), but the email body gets printed.

```
<div>You are performing account verification operation , the verification code is:  **<b>4740</b>**</div>

<div>This verification code can only be used once, and it will automatically become invalid after verification.</div>

<div>(Please complete the verification within 30 minutes, the verification code will become invalid after 30 minutes, you need to verify again.)</div>

<div>Please ignore this email if we send the wrong address, thanks.</div>

<div> team</div>

</body>
</html>

this is email:false
null
this is email:[null]
the text is:[null]
NO MATCH
```

Comment: Yes, your List isn't empty. It contains a single element that is `null`. This is no contradiction as Lists are allowed to contain `null` as elements. You need to find out why `emailUtils.getUnreadMessageByFromEmail` returns you a `List` that only has `null` in it. But since you didn't share the code of that method we can't help you with that.

Comment: The method that I posted is the only method that I am using. As you can see on console I am able to get the email body but when printing the emailtext variable its not accessing it.

Comment: I am also getting a yellow line on the ArrayList saying "Type Safety: the expression of type list needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<String>"

Comment: emailUtils.getUnreadMessageByFromEmail is an inbuilt method of emailUtils.

Comment: Well, whatever that class EmailUtils is it isn't part of Javas standard classes. I just assumed it is something you yourself wrote. If it is from some third party library it might be helpful if you added information which one it is.